# Looking to Aggregate 3 Counts of Data as columns by distinct account number in a given list. All of my data is in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the basic of what I am trying to do in pseudo code.  All of my data I need is in the same table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT_NUMBER
    , COUNT(INVOICES FOR INV_DATE WITHN 2022)
    , COUNT(INVOICES FOR INV_DATE WITHIN 2021)
    , COUNT(INVOICES FOR INV_DATE WITHIN 2020)
FROM SALES_DATA
WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN ('987987','98845','966554').
```

I can easily get the first columns, but joining the additional years I am struggling.

Comment: select account_number, count(case when year(inv_date) = 2022 then 1 end), ..., from sales_data where inv_date >= '20200101' and account_number in ... group by account_number`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT` after collapsing the invoices to just the account number and year:

```
; -- previous statement terminator sqlblog.org/cte
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, y = DATEPART(YEAR, INV_DATE)
    FROM dbo.SALES_DATA
    WHERE INV_DATE >= '20200101'
    -- AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN (some,list)
)
SELECT * FROM cte
PIVOT 
(
  COUNT(y) FOR y IN ([2020],[2021],[2022])
) AS p;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=816ffbb2044820780ce0495cdbcd6050)